# Difference between running React and Express on different port vs on same port

Tags: reactjs, express, web, server

I wanted to know what are the key differences that one should consider while following an architecture that runs the front end React.JS app and the Express server backend on two different ports vs running both of them on the same port?

Are there any deployment or performance issues while implementing one approach over the other?